# adding new values to pandas df and increment timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series dataset of a Pandas series df that I am trying to add a new value to the bottom of the df and then increment the timestamp which is the df index.

For example the new value I can add to the bottom of the df like this:

```
testday.loc[len(testday.index)] = testday_predict[0]

print(testday)
```

Which seems to work but the time stamp is just incremented:

```
    kW
Date    
2022-07-29 00:00:00 39.052800
2022-07-29 00:15:00 38.361600
2022-07-29 00:30:00 38.361600
2022-07-29 00:45:00 38.534400
2022-07-29 01:00:00 38.880000
... ...
2022-07-29 23:00:00 36.806400
2022-07-29 23:15:00 36.806400
2022-07-29 23:30:00 36.633600
2022-07-29 23:45:00 36.806400
96  44.482361    <---- my predicted value added at the bottom good except for the time stamp value of 96
```

Like the value of `96` is just the next value in the length of the df.index hopefully this makes sense.

If I try:

```
from datetime import timedelta

last_index_stamp = testday.last_valid_index()

print(last_index_stamp)
```

This returns:

```
Timestamp('2022-07-29 23:45:00')
```

And then I can add 15 minutes to this Timestamp (my data is 15 minute data) like this:

```
new_timestamp = last_index_stamp + timedelta(minutes=15)

print(new_timestamp)
```

Which returns what I am looking instead of the value of `96`:

```
Timestamp('2022-07-30 00:00:00')
```

But how do I replace the value of `96` with `new_timestampt`? If I try:

```
testday.index[-1:] = new_timestamp
```

This will error out:

```
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

Any tips greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
testday.loc[new_timestamp,:] = testday_predict[0]
```

Comment: Nice work that totally does work!